# angular2 how to access children static data

Tags: angular

I'd like to know how can I access children static data when navigating to "/account/someId"

I check that property using

```
this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data.title
```

and I get "Create User Account" while I was expecting "Manage Subscriptions".

app-routing.ts

```
export function GetChildRoutes() {
return [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'account' },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: 'app/account/account.module#AccountModule',
    data: <IRouteDataCustomized>{
      icon: 'user-plus',
      title: 'Create User Account',
      isMenuItem: true
    },
  }
];
}
```

account-routing.ts

```
export function GetChildRoutes(): Route[] {
return [{
  path: '',
  component: AccountComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', component: AccountAddComponent },
    {
      path: ':id',
      component: AccountEditComponent,
      data: <IRouteDataCustomized>{
        icon: 'user-plus',
        title: 'Manage Subscriptions',
        isMenuItem: false
      }
    },
  ]
}];
}
```

Comment: That's a good question. I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you find a solution ?